# Amazon EC2 Unable to view website

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm unable to to view my website.
I have just set a new instance and attached it an elastic ip.
I've also installed apache,mysql,php on the Amazon EC2 instance.
and configured the apache httpd.conf virtualhost to redirect to some directory inside

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mail@example.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/app/current/example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

In my GoDaddy domain.
I've added A host (@), that points to the Elastic IP from amazon ec2.

And after all of that i'm unable to view the website.
What Am I missing?

Comment: Have you configure your security group for your ec2 instance yet? At port 80

Comment: Also try your check your EIP first, edit your hosts file in your local workstation and point it to your EIP.

Comment: @Kevin Opening port 80 solve it, Thanks!

Comment: Please select my answer below to mark this problem resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open port 80 in security group for your instance.